# NaN for an unknown reason

Tags: javascript, nan

While coding a little project I came across a NaN issue when printing to the console.  I thought this would be easily remedied by using the JavaScript code:

```
newInt = parseInt(oldInt);
```

This was not to be the case.  After reading up on NaN, it can be created in a number of ways, such as adding an array to an object, or more commonly when you try to take away a number from a string.  I say take away because adding a number to a string means that concatenation will occur.

My code is available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8okcwL53/).  It is all one website, however I use appearing and disappearing divs to appear that it's not.  To get the error, press "Start the Adventure".  You can use default values.

In console, which you can access by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>, it will print off a set of starting values.  Then it will print a set of starting values, conveniently grouped together using:

```
console.Group();
console.GroupEnd();
```

After that, when you press "Next Year!" it will print two more groups.  The first one created by the function

```
plantCrops();
```

The next one created by the function

```
buildWells();
```

As you can see, both currentCrop comments are NaN - despite taking precauations by using parseInt a lot.  Is there any way to fix this?  It seems strange that it's happening despite the fact that it should be very simple.

Comment: I realise that, but I've used parseInt a lot, so why isn't it a number?  If I understand correctly, when taking a value from an input, it is always a string.  Shouldn't parseInt fix it?

Comment: parseInt may not fix, if the input is not in the expected format

Comment: When testing, I did enter a number.  I can't see any reason why it's a string.  I've made sure to include no spaces or other characters.

Comment: Are you sure all the ID's you are requested, e.g. `document.getElementById("cropstored")` are correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code have a number of issues, but the one that is relevant to the NaN is here:

```
currentCrop = document.getElementById("cropstored");
currentCrop = parseInt(currentCrop);
```

This code tries to parse int from the object, which does not work.

Get the value first:

```
currentCrop = document.getElementById("cropstored").value;
currentCrop = parseInt(currentCrop);
```

But make sure that the element does not contain empty string as the `parseInt` returns `NaN` for it:

```
parseInt('') -> NaN
```

Actually, `NaN` is indication that the value cannot be parsed to integer so you can use it as indication of the invalid data.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript

```
console.log(parseInt(''));
```

will yield NaN.

If you add

```
console.log('cc'+ currentCrop);
console.log('a' + parseInt(acres));
```

in `plantCrops()` you will observe that they are both NaN if no value is provided in the text boxes.

Also, for `currentCrop`, I would believe that this is the line that is messing it up:

```
currentCrop = document.getElementById("cropstored");
```

even if there is a default value at the top.

The solution would be a simple string equality test before the `parseInt()` calls using the `===` operator:

```
if(someString === '') 
    defaultValue = ...;
else
    parseInt();
```